# Not getting paypal webhook notifications from older subscriptions

Tags: paypal, webhooks, payment, paypal-ipn

I'm stuck at handling paypal notifications, and looking for some potential solutions.

I'm working on a upgraded/new site where users can subscribe and get access to premium materials - pretty standard stuff. Old site is currently running, and people have subscriptions there and the challenge is to keep those subscriptions running and have smooth transition to a new site.

Now i built new site on rest API and webhooks, and imported all subscriptions data from old site - this part is working, i can request subscription through rest api from paypal and i will get correct info, hovewer im not getting any notifications on my registered webhook from transactions that were made on old site (subsequent payments). When i subscribed on live with new site, notification about payment come through, same as on sandbox environment.

I figured out that the old site is using NVP/SOAP api, so my guessing is thats the reason why im not getting any notifications - am I right about it ?

Webhooks works in sandbox mode, and on live as long as the subscription was created through rest api.

I can make another NVP/SOAP app and setup it for my new site - then i can develop notification handler for that NVP/SOAP api but i don't know if this would receive those notifications then, or they are tied to that application that old site uses ?

I have webhook subscribed to all events and im logging any requests to it, so far the only one that came was from payment i made through new site - so i know it is working.

I would appreciate any help i can get on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

The classic NVP/SOAP API does not have a concept of "applications"; its API calls are tied directly to the account.

So when you create an NVP/SOAP webhook listener, it should receive all events for the account.